# help with oauthService and linkedin

Tags: grails, grails-controller

I am trying to iterate over a list of parameters, in a grails controller.  when I have a list, longer than one element, like this:

```
     [D4L2DYJlSw, 8OXQWKDDvX]
```

the following code works fine:

```
def recipientId = params.email
recipientId.each { test->
     System.print(test + "\n")  
}
```

The output being:

```
  A4L2DYJlSw
  8OXQWKDDvX
```

But, if the list only has one item, the output is not the only item, but each letter in the list.  for example, if my params list is :

```
 A4L2DYJlSwD
```

using the same code as above, the output becomes:

```
 A
 4
 L
 2
 D
 Y
 J
 l
 S
 w
```

can anyone tell me what's going on and what I am doing wrong?

thanks

jason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I run at the same problem a while ago! My solution for that it was

```
def gameId = params.gameId
def selectedGameList = gameId.class.isArray() ? Game.getAll(gameId as List) : Game.get(gameId);
```

because in my case I was getting 1 or more game Ids as parameters!

What you can do is the same:

```
def recipientId = params.email
if(recipientId.class.isArray()){
 // smtg
}else{
  // smtg
}
```

Because what is happening here is, as soon as you call '.each' groovy transform that object in a list! and 'String AS LIST' in groovy  means char_array of that string!

Comment: Thanks, your suggestion worked.  I'm not sure if this is the best way to solve the problem, but it is functional

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be (from what I've seen with groovy elsewhere) is that it is trying to figure out what the type for `recipientId` should be since you haven't given it one (and it's thus dynamic).

In your first example, groovy decided what got passed to the `.each{}` closure was a `List<String>`.  The second example, as there is only one `String`, groovy decides the type should be `String` and `.each{}` knows how to iterate over a `String` too - it just converts it to a `char[]`.

You could simply make `recipientId` a `List<String>` I think in this case.

Comment: thanks for your response.  i tried adding the List<String> as you suggested.  Again, though, it works fine for a list larger than 1 but if the list only has one value, i get this error: Cannot cast object '8OXQWKDDvX' with class 'java.lang.String' to class 'java.util.List'

Comment: True that.  Sorry, I can't remember off the top of my head how I did solve this.  Arthur's answer seems workable if not completely idiomatic.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try like this:

```
def recipientId = params.email instanceof List ? params.email : [params.email]
recipientId.each { test-> System.print(test + "\n") }
```

It will handle both the cases ..

Answer (score 0):

Grails provides a built-in way to guarantee that a specific parameter is a list, even when only one was submitted.  This is actually the preferred way to get a list of items when the number of items may be 0, 1, or more:

```
def recipientId = params.list("email")
recipientId.each { test->
     System.print(test + "\n")  
}
```

The `params` object will wrap a single item as a list, or return the list if there is more than one.